# How to set postgresql client charset using PHPs PDO layer?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

It seems PHP PosgreSQL PDO driver does not accept charset parameter.

This does not work (as charset is missing in doc at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php):

```
$db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=WIN1250', 'user', 'pass');
```

How can I set charset witch client is using?

Comment: `SET NAMES`? Are you sure this is PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes I am. :-) At least everything works. See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/multibyte.html#AEN27550

Comment: Thankyou; I had no idea that PostgreSQL supported `NAMES` as an alias for `client_encoding` despite using the DB for years. Interesting. (It's a good idea to show `select version()` in your questions by the way). It isn't clear if your *edit* means that you actually found a solution to the problem or not. If you did, undelete your answer and explain it a little more.

Comment: Ok, I did revert my edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found possibilities of how to set client charset in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/multibyte.html#AEN27550) and it seems followed query works fine:

```
SET NAMES 'WIN1250';
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @TI users are entitled to answer their own questions. So, nothing wrong with this one.